# With javascript, get label text in div wrapped in LinkButton in datalist?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-4.0

I have a `Panel` with a `ModalPopupExtender` that displays a data-bound `DataList`. The aspx markup looks like the following.

Essentially, the user clicks on `ButtonOpenPopup` and the `Panel` with the datalist is displayed. The user then clicks on a datalist item, which represents a `RoomNUm`.

As you can see, there's also a `TextBox` called `TextBoxNewRoomNum`. The purpose of this `TextBox` is to display the RoomNum that was clicked on in the `DataList`.

The issue is that this needs to be done without the webform doing any `postback`. I've tried different function calls with `OnClientClick`, but nothing's worked. Most often than not, the panel disappears with the click.

My question is: How can I transfer the value of RoomNum of the clicked datalist item into the `TextBox` TextBoxNewRoomNum? I prefer no jquery.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderRoom" runat="server" PopupControlID="PanelRoomDetail" 
TargetControlID="btnDummy">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonOpenPopup" runat="server" Text="PopUp" onclick="ButtonOpenPopup_Click"  />

<asp:Button ID="btnDummy" runat="server" Text="PopUp" style = "display:none" />

<asp:Panel ID="PanelRoomDetail" runat="server" style="width:600px; height: 600px;display:none">
    <div>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataListFloorThumb" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div >
                <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick='return ShowRoom(<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>);'>
                    <div style='width:72px;height:72px; background-image:url(<%# Eval("image_path_thumbnail","Styles/Images/{0}") %>)'>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" CommandName="cmd_RoomNum" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>' 
                                runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>' ></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNewRoomNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `return false;` to your ShowRoom() JavaScript method.  That will stop the postback.

The LinkButton has the runat="server" attribute which will cause it to initiate a postback every time it's clicked.  That's probably the reason the panel disappears.

EDIT:
Per your comments, I'm pretty sure that using `<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>` for the ShowRoom() method's parameter is causing the problem.

When I have done similar things I've used the `this` keyword for the parameter's value. e.g. `OnClientClick='return ShowRoom(this);'`  Then in the ShowRoom() method use that parameter with jQuery to navigate to the span element that holds the room number.

```
function ShowRoom(linkButton) {
   var span = $(linkButton).Find(span)[0];
   alert(span.innerHTML);

   return false;
}
```

Comment: I changed OnClientClict to `OnClientClick='ShowRoom(302);'` and changed the javascript function to `function ShowRoom(room) { alert(room); return false; }` and the panel still closes (after the `alert` is displayed).

Comment: Just for a test, remove the runat='server attribute from the LinkButton and try it again.  If the panel doesn't dissapear, that means it's a postback causing the issue and "return false;" is not stopping the postback.

Comment: What I posted before was my mistake. I changed to `OnClientClick='return ShowRoom(302);'` and  the function to `function ShowRoom(room) { alert(room); return false; }` and the panel does not disappear after the `alert`.

Comment: But if I change `OnClientClick` to `OnClientClick='return ShowRoom(<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>);'` then the `Panel` disappears and the `alert` is not displayed. Which means there's something wrong with the call.

Comment: That probably means that a JavaScript error occurs when your ShowRoom() event handler is called.  I'll update my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: The call was incorrect. It should be like this: `OnClientClick='<%# "return ShowRoom(" + Eval("BedNum") + ");" %>'`